# Rock Paper Scissors syntax explanation

Tags: ruby

```
def play(i)
  s=%w[Rock Paper Scissors]
  p=s.index i
  s[c=rand(3)]+",#{p==c ?:Draw: p&&p==-~c%3?:Win: :Lose}"
end
play("Rock")
```

Could I ask for help explaining syntax

```
 s[c=rand(3)]+",#{p==c ?:Draw: p&&p==-~c%3?:Win: :Lose}"
```

It is ternary if than else overall, but what are other symbols like +",# or -~c%3

Comment: You should probably add spaces so the code is less terrible. Granted, spaces won't fix it, since whoever wrote this apparently didn't care for readability, but it'll at least help you identify the operators in use. Also, `+",#` isn't a symbol, neither is `-~c%3`. Again, add spaces. And know your operators.

Comment: That is horribly written code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meditate  on this, and read about operators like `~` and `%`:

```
ROCK_PAPER_SCISSORS = %w[Rock Paper Scissors]

def play(i)
  p = ROCK_PAPER_SCISSORS.index i
  response = rand(3)

  win_lose_draw = if (p == response)
    :Draw
  else
    if (p && p == -~response % 3)
      :Win
    else
      :Lose
    end
  end

  ROCK_PAPER_SCISSORS[response] + ",#{ win_lose_draw }"
end

puts play("Rock")
```

In my opinion, whoever write the original is enamored with writing obscure and unreadable code, thinking it's macho, or was trying to write something that was marginally obfuscated. Either way, don't try to imitate that example, especially in Ruby.

In C and Perl, such things are common, though not really of any benefit. In the "old days", back before there were pencils and we programmed using mud tablets and sticks, we were saddled with compilers that couldn't optimize their way out of a bag, so people tried writing "tight" code to improve performance. There's a lot more to writing tight code than being terse and obscure though; Something called efficiency is supposed to be involved too, but that often got left behind.

Today's compilers and interpreters are a lot smarter, so the reason behind writing such code is largely gone. People like to write obscure code as a challenge to write something functional in as small a space as possible "just because", but it's not something to do in a real programming environment, where you'll have team members needing to read and understand it, especially at 3AM after they've been out on the town and get a call from some panicking sysadmin.

Comment: You have been real help. Appreciate your attitude and effort. You must be a very kind person.